# What's the meaning of "openshift_master_cluster_method=native"?

Tags: ansible, openshift, cluster-computing

I am writing an inventory file to deploy an openshift cluster using ansible playbook. While reading some samples I came across the variable openshift_master_cluster_method=native. It is used to state the method of clustering but I don't know what the native and other methods are and how do they differ from each other.

openshift_master_cluster_method=native

Comment: This should be a good reading start point: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.3/install_config/install/advanced_install.html#multiple-masters. If I understand well, it's an optionnal parameter describing the HA method you want to use when deploying multiple masters that will currently accept a single value: `native`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarification, more information is here. Refer [Modifying the Ansible Inventory](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/install_config/upgrading/pacemaker_to_native_ha.html#pm-native-playbooks-modifying-the-ansible-inventory) for more details.
`native` is only option for `HA` in a recent version, but the `pacemaker` could be available as option of `HA` at old version.

Comparison of HA options are as follows.

- `Native` : it means a usual load balancer method and **only this option** can be available for `HA` at a recent version (maybe ... more than v3.5 ?).

```
# Native high availability cluster method with optional load balancer.
# If no lb group is defined, the installer assumes that a load balancer has
# been preconfigured. For installation the value of
# openshift_master_cluster_hostname must resolve to the load balancer
# or to one or all of the masters defined in the inventory if no load
# balancer is present.
openshift_master_cluster_method=native
```

- `Pacemaker` : VIP solution for HA.

```
# Pacemaker high availability cluster method.
# Pacemaker HA environment must be able to self provision the
# configured VIP. For installation openshift_master_cluster_hostname
# must resolve to the configured VIP.
#openshift_master_cluster_method=pacemaker
```

I hope it help you. :)